# Template is not correctly selecting the right name

Tags: docusignapi

I have a template with 2 signing tabs. I made the first tab #Seller, the second tab is #Buyer. I enter names for both these people and send out the document. For some reason, it has the correct name for the #Seller position, but the #Buyer does not have its corresponding name. The document makes its way to the correct parties with no problem, but that second signing tab now says #Buyer as the recipients name. Is anyone else seeing this weird behavior? This is being done thru their web site and not thru the api calls.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in my contact list that the person in question was listed as #Buyer, not their real name. So I believe that it occurred accidentally and since Docusign keeps this list of contacts, that the error kept continuing.